# Angular + Jasmine, move test to the common module. Service -> undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I took the frequently used test in the common module `globals.js`:

```
const user = {
  username: 'Skat',
  password: '123',
  role: 'user',
};

function relogin(user, authService) {
  describe('--> relogin', () => {
    it('--> ' + user.role + ', ' + user.username, async () => {
      authService.logout();
      expect(authService.isLogged()).toBe(false);
      authService.login(user.username, user.password).subscribe();
      await delay(800);
      expect(authService.isLogged()).toBe(true);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.user = user;
module.exports.relogin = relogin;
```

Calling a shared test from `service.spec.ts`:

```
const globals = require('../globals');

describe('AdvertService', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        AuthService
      ],
    });
  });

  it('Injected services should be created', inject([AuthService], async (authService1: AuthService) => {
      expect(authService).toBeFalsy();
      authService = authService1;
      expect(authService).toBeTruthy();
    }
  ));

  globals.relogin(globals.user, authService);

});
```

As a result, the test from the common module fails due to:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined

[test fail printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V09ru.png)

But the service object was definitely created, just for some reason `undefined` came to the common module.

Please tell me how do I pass the service object in the test, which I move in the common module?

Answer (score 0):

Try to first tell your test case that its async, then inject your service. like so:

```
it('Injected services should be created', async(inject([AuthService], (authService1: AuthService) => {
      expect(authService).toBeFalsy();
      authService = authService1;
      expect(authService).toBeTruthy();
    }
)));
```

Comment: tried as you advised - the same error: Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined

Comment: why is `globals.relogin(globals.user, authService);` not inside a test suite?

Comment: This is a frequently used suite of tests that I want to reuse in others *.spec.ts

Comment: Ok, thats fine but if `globals.relogin(globals.user, authService);` is not inside a test suite, that means it doesnt have an injected instance of the service available, since it gets injected into an `it()` suite.

Comment: `globals.relogin` is inside `describe('AdvertService', () => { let authService: AuthService;... globals.relogin(, authService)});` and the service object should see, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not perse, because `let authService: AuthService;` doesnt inject the service, it just declares a variable. You only inject your service once you `it('Injected services should be created', async(inject([AuthService], (authService1: AuthService)`

Comment: It turns out that in my case it will be impossible to re-use the code? Maybe there is some other way?